# Converting Excel Date Columns With VBA Macro?

Tags: excel

I'm stuck trying to work out the vba code to convert a column of excel date\time values into a string value of just the time in 24 hour format (HH:MM).

I can read the property when I loop through the collection, but i'm unable to set the formatting:

```
 Dim dt As Date
 Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Range("sheet2!E2:E100")
 DIm i As Integer
 For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
     dt = rng.Cells(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:="E").Value
     rng.Cells(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:="E").NumberFormat = "@" '// <-- Exception Here
     rng.Cells(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:="E").Value = Format(dt, "HH:MM")
 Next
```

1. Why is it throwing an exception?
2. I'm trying to run this on entire column E, but E1 is a header, and the size of E is unknown, how can i account for this?

Comment: What is the "exception"?  What is the value of `i` when it errors?  What is the contents of `Ei` when it errors?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you're getting an exception but the following code works for me:

```
Sub StringTime()

Dim rng As Range
Dim lRow As Long
Dim strTime As String

'find last row
lRow = Range("E1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

Set rng = Range("E2:E" & lRow)

For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    strTime = Hour(rng.Cells(i).Value) & ":" & Minute(rng.Cells(i).Value)
    rng.Cells(i).NumberFormat = "@"
    rng.Cells(i).Value = strTime
Next i

End Sub
```

Note that I'm finding the last row in column E before setting the range. This will fix your variable size problem.